# Autorun python script on linux when connected to wifi

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x, scripting

Whenever i connect to my collage wifi i have to login to access the internet.so i made a python script to autologin to the network. But i have to manually run the script. I want to run the script automaticallly whenever my laptop is connected to the internet.

Comment: iwgetid can get the connected wifi name. How about setting a cron job that checks the wifi name, when the wifi name is the one you concern, then run your auto login script?

Comment: I am preety new to scripting so if you can guide me to some tutorial or link.. it would be nice.. thanks in advance